# AR браузер работает на компьютере, но не на телефоне

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, augmented-reality

не могли бы вы мне помочь ... это видео с канала Мэтью Холлберга, которое он выпустил два года назад, вот ссылка: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMLSACaaOjU У меня проблема ... Мэтью в своем видео показывает, как запустить приложение для macbook, а у меня windows ... тем не менее, мне удалось запустить приложение для windows, но приложение не работает на телефоне .. Вы не случайно не знаете в чем может быть проблема? На компьютере приложение работает, а на телефоне такое же приложение не работает ... Все сделал как показано на видео ... и еще одно: в комментариях люди у которых Windows написали, что у них тоже такая проблема ... Может то что нужно менять в AndroidManifest? и еще кое-что: чтобы приложение работало в единстве, вам нужно зарегистрировать свой ip-адрес в некоторых скриптах, а затем зарегистрировать некоторые команды в таких приложениях, как Homebrew или Chocolatey ...
Когда запускаю приложение на телефоне выдает следующие ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка вам явно говорит, что вам не разрешено использовать HTTP, используйте HTTPS

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ!:) когда я использую HTTPS, мне в консоли в юнити при запуске приложения выбивает ошибку:
Unable to complete SSL connection
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<GetImageFromURL>d__11:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/BrowserController.cs:78)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

Comment: Это уже другая ошибка. Чтобы работал HTTPS, надо иметь сертификат на сервере, можно получить бесплатный, чтобы получить сертификат, надо иметь домен, на который этот сертификат привязывается. В общем, решайте как заставить работать HTTPS, политика безопасности мобильника не позволит вам работать по HTTP.

Comment: понял, спасибо, буду пробовать:)